# Quoting bash command for perl to execute

Tags: bash, perl

I've spent like an hour on this without success. Got this perl script which I want to call a wrapper bash function:

```
my $command = qq(source ~/.bashrc; do_osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to return URL of current tab of window 1');

my $url = `/usr/local/bin/bash -c '$command'`;
logd $url;
```

And here is the wrapper bash function:

```
function do_osascript() {
    if [ -e "/Library/QuickTime/EyeTV MPEG Support.component" ]; then
        mv "/Library/QuickTime/EyeTV MPEG Support.component" ~
    fi
    command osascript "$@"
    if [ -e "${HOME}/EyeTV MPEG Support.component" ]; then
        mv "${HOME}/EyeTV MPEG Support.component" "/Library/QuickTime/"
    fi
}
```

UPDATE: Had some old code for bash. Updated.

I've tried many different methods of escaping quotes but none of them work. I have confirmed that the command works fine when run from the command line.

Comment: Putting the code in a function is just weird. Put it in a script file in your `PATH`. Moving the com+onent back and forth is also extremely suspicious. Would symlinking it to your home directory (just once) not work?

Comment: OK, I put it in a script and it works. I originally had it in a function called "osascript" to override the system binary called "osascript" because of a bug with the Quicktime component. I always have to move it out of the way or I get buttload of errors every time I use the osascript binary.

Comment: https://www.perl.com/article/quoting-the-shell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest stingle quotes like that.  For debugging, try

```
my $url = `printf '>>%s<<\n' /usr/local/bin/bash -c '$command'`,
print "$url";
exit;
```

to see how the command is tokenized by the shell.

The simplest fix I can think of is

```
my $command = qq(source ~/.bashrc; do_osascript -e 'tell application \\"Safari\\" to return URL of current tab of window 1');
my $url = `printf '>>%s<<\n' /usr/local/bin/bash -c "$command"`;
```

where I added backslash escapes before the double quotes in `$command`, and switched from single to double quotes in `$url`.  But seriously, having that function in your `.bashrc` is just weird. Put it in a script file instead and do away with the requirement to `bash -c "source ~/.bashrc;"` before the actual command.

Comment: Double slashing did the trick and putting $command in double quotes did the trick. Of all the different iterations I tried, I guess I didn't try that one.

Comment: I would recommend against trying to defeat bash quoting manually when String::ShellQuote exists.

Comment: As outlined in the last paragraph, the proper solution in this case is to not avoid the problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) to programmatically quote an argument or list of arguments so a bourne-compatible shell will treat each as a single argument, regardless of what it contains:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use String::ShellQuote;

my $command = shell_quote '/usr/local/bin/bash', '-c', qq(source ~/.bashrc; do_osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to return URL of current tab of window 1');

my $url = `$command`;
```

Or invoke the program directly without having the shell parse it. There are many options for this, but the direct analogue of backticks would be using [IPC::ReadpipeX](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::ReadpipeX):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::ReadpipeX;

my $command = qq(source ~/.bashrc; do_osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to return URL of current tab of window 1');

my $url = readpipex '/usr/local/bin/bash', '-c', $command;
```

Other good options for this are listed in that module's docs under [SEE ALSO](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::ReadpipeX#SEE-ALSO).